# How do I separate a part of an input and convert it into a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I'm working on a simple program and I was wondering how can I separate a part of the input and turn that separated part into a variable.

For example: `START {chrome.exe}`.

Basically I want to take that string in between those curly brackets and turn it into a variable.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean "turn it into a variable"? Do you want a variable to contain that string (e.g. `some_var = "chrome.exe"`) or do you want to create a variable _named_ `chrome.exe`? Please take the [tour] and read read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). You need to provide an unambiguous description of the expected output, and show your attempt to achieve what you want as a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of operation, it is a good idea to use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).
Python has a builtin module for using regexes, called `re`. You can use its `findall` function to find all the strings which match a certain pattern, and then simply get the first item in the resulting list (which will only have one item anyway).

---

Here is what the code would look like:

```py
import re

inp = input()
var = re.findall(r"{(.*?)}", inp)

print(var)
```

Given an input of:

```
START {chrome.exe}
```

This outputs:

```
chrome.exe
```

---

Here is an explanation of how the regex works:

- The `{` and `}` characters match the literal characters `{` and `}`
- The `(` and `)` characters are special characters which group together tokens
- The `.` character is a special character which matches any character except newlines
- The `*` character is a special character which means that the last token can match any number of itself (not just 1). This means that the `.` will now match a run of multiple non-newline characters, not just one character
- The `?` character is a special character which alters the meaning of the preceding `*`. Now, instead of matching as many characters as possible ("greedy"), which would cause the `.*` to continue after the `}` and match the whole rest of the string, the `.*?` matches as few characters as possible ("lazy"), so it only matches up to the next `}` character